# Bind ZonedDateTime to bean from application.properties

Tags: spring-boot

I want to bind the current date to a bean via application.properties. I tried using a spell expression but it didn't work.

`application.yml`

```
defaults:
  date: #{T(java.time.ZonedDateTime).now()}
```

And I have a java bean with getters and setters.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "defaults")
public class DefaultProperties {
    private ZonedDateTime date;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

The trouble is that the expression is always parsing as a string .  I am getting `Reason: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.ZonedDateTime'`

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Why are doing this?when u can dynamically generate date inside ur java code then doing it in yaml file..

Comment: Because the example I give above is a much simpler version of what I am actually trying to do.  I don't want to go into the details because it is boring but it would be convenient in my case to be able to define this in YAML. I realise I can easily `private ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.now()` but this is not useful in the problem I am trying to solve.